# Cannot access db result in Nodejs, it always returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
 var robject=[]; 
 async.waterfall([
        function (callback) {
            for(var i in serial){
                Router.find({},{r_serial_no:serial[i]},function (err,routerData) {
                    robject = robject.concat(routerData);
                });
            }
            console.log('Robject= '+robject); //THIS RETURNS NULL
            callback(null, robject);
        },
        function (blogs, callback) {
            res.render('index', {dispatched_data:dispatched_data });
            callback(null, 'Ended..' );
        }

    ], function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

this is my waterfall model, here i need to access the `robject` from schema.find method to outside of that method. but it always return null..
how to access that??

Comment: First check are you getting anything in routerData ? It can be actually null.

Comment: no bro, inside the loop i get the data..

Comment: Why would you project different fields from a query result in a loop? Why not do the query **once** and simply "loop the keys" to match the names in the array? Your problem here is without callback control the "loop" completes before the actual calls are made. But it's also completely unnecessary. Do the `find()` **once** and simply extract the values from the matching keys.

Comment: Moreover it actually looks like you really want `$in` here instead. i.e `Router.find({ "r_serial_no": { "$in": serial } },function(err,routerData) {..` As you appear to want to "query" but you are putting the values in the "projection" part in error.

Comment: @Neil Lunn Bro.. u made my day.. thank you verry much..
actually i dont need a loop.. you are correct, i can put the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

You have the syntax error:

```
 for(var i in serial){
                Router.find({},{r_serial_no: i},function (err,routerData) {
                    robject = robject.concat(routerData);
                });
            }
```

the "for" loop defines "i" as next item in the array each iteration

Comment: bro that too works.. my problem is with accessing the variable. if i log inside the for loop i get the result.

Comment: try to remove all the conditions from the .find method, and fetch all results from db

Comment: bro thats not resolved the issue. still i cant access the variable

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see here is in `for...in` loop. Your callback will be fired even if your process i.e. `Router.find` is not completed. You can try below code, It might help.

Unlike your `serial` object please create a array called `serials`.

```js
var robject=[]; 
 async.waterfall([
        function (callback) {
            async.each(serials,
              function(serial, localCb){
                Router.find({},{r_serial_no:serial},function (err,routerData) {
                    robject = robject.concat(routerData);
                    localCb()
                });
              },
              function(err){
                console.log('Robject= '+robject); 
                callback(null, robject);
              }
          ); 
        },
        function (blogs, callback) {
            res.render('index', {dispatched_data:dispatched_data });
            callback(null, 'Ended..' );
        }

    ], function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
```